# How to destructure an array/object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I want to destructure this but i can't get it (I need the vcardArray)

I can't get it with `.vcardArray` or with `const { vcardArray } = *variablename`

```
[
    { 
        objectClassName: 'entity', 
        handle: '292', 
        roles: ['registrar'], 
        publicIds: [[Object]], 
        vcardArray: ['vcard', [Array]], 
        entities: [[Object]]
    }
]
```

Comment: Folks: Is this a duplicate of [*How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)? I couldn't decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructuring syntax is exactly the same as object and array literal syntax,¹ it's just interpreted the other way around (and it's more common for us to use the shorthand `{name}` form than the full `{name: name}` form, though both are used).

So if you think about how you'd create an array with an object with a `vcardArray` property, that's how you destructure it.

```
const [ { vcardArray } ] = /*...your object...*/;
```

---

¹ With one caveat: The innermost tokens have to be assignable targets, so they can't be literals. `{example: 42}` is a valid object literal (creating an object with an `example` property and setting that property to `42`), but you can't use it as a destructuring pattern because it would mean "get the `example` property and assign it to `42`" you can't assign to the literal `42`.